# How to revert to system vim after using installing vim with homebrew?

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I wanted to upgrade to vim 7.4+ but the macOS system version was 7.3. I used the command `brew install vim --override-system-vim` however I don't think overriding system defaults is ever a good idea. How can I revert the changes back to the system defaults?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Just remove `/usr/local/bin/vi` (which is a symbolic link to brew's vi).</s>
Run `brew rm vim && brew install vim`.

Making the symbolic link is all what `--override-system-vim` do.
Brew actually doesn't do anything with system vi.